# unable to install unity tweak tool on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, dependencies, unity-tweak-tool

When I try to install `unity-tweak-tool` I get this message. I searched a lot but found nothing to solve my problem.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-tweak-tool : Depends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you tried running `sudo apt install -f`? Which is your Ubuntu version (you can check it with this command: `lsb_release -a`)?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy unity-tweak-tool unity-webapps-common` and `apt-get install -s unity-webapps-common`? Thanks.